# How to setup docker-compose.yml to have an app batch run a list of local files in a cluster?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I want to run vascobnunes/l8_reflectance image on several files, in a distributed form to several nodes.

To run just for one file i'm successfully doing:

```
Docker run -v /path/to/local/input/L8imagedir:/inputpath/in/container -v /path/to/local/output/L8imagedir:/outputpath/in/container vascobnunes/l8_reflectance:latest /inputpath/in/container /outputpath/in/container
```

But now I'm trying to figure out how to write the docker-compose.yml file in order to properly distribute the processing of the files through a cluster (swarm).

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

This is what I tried with no luck:

```
version: "3"
services:
  l8_reflectance:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: vascobnunes/l8_reflectance:v0.0.5
    volumes:
        - LC08_L1TP_203032_20190513_20190513_01_RT:/root/app/LC08_L1TP_203032_20190513_20190513_01_RT
        - app:/root/app/
    args:
        LC08_L1TP_203032_20190513_20190513_01_RT
        app
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```